# Issue with prefers-color-scheme media query

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries

I am using svg favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg">
```

and I want to toggle favicon in dark mode browser so my code in svg file looks like

```
circle {
      fill: red;
      stroke: yellow;
    }
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  circle  {fill: yellow;
        stroke: red; }
  }
```

But when I change my browser to dark mode favicon doesn’t toggle.

Can anyone help me with this?

Chrome version : Version 89.0.4389.90
Firefox version: 87.0 (64-bit)
Ubuntu: 16.04

Comment: Currently I think you'd need to restart your browser. I don't think they support dynamic dark mode changes, so pick a mode and stick with it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the suggestion. I tried restarting the browser with `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. Still it doesn't change

Comment: You might want to edit your example svg code so it is complete. That makes for better reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically changing the favicon based on the color scheme works, but requires a reload after the scheme has changed. Here's a complete example:

```html
<!-- icon.svg -->
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    circle {
      fill: yellow;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      circle {
        fill: black;
        stroke: yellow;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" />
</svg>
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" />
```

You can see this [deployed](https://dark-mode-favicon.glitch.me/) on Glitch, and read more details about it in my [blog post](https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/09/21/prefers-color-scheme-in-svg-favicons-for-dark-mode-icons/).

Comment: Both the solution and the glitch example do not work on Firefox 88.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 when using 'Toggle dark color scheme simulation for the page' in developer tools (even with reloading the page).
The color of the tab title doesn't depend on the dark mode or light mode of the browser, but rather on the browser theme, so even if it did work, it probably wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: This seems to be a Firefox choice then that they decouple browser UI and page rendering. It works in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone, remember the operative system theme is the one used for prefers-color-scheme media query. For example I was simulating the media query using chrome devtools but it did not change, was because i was using always light theme on windows.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/rendering/emulate-css