# Firefox Ignore media tag prefers-color-scheme?

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="file:///C:/Users/daj/Desktop/favicon-dark.ico" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="file:///C:/Users/daj/Desktop/favicon-light.ico" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like Mozilla Firefox always takes the last link and ignores the media tag.
My Firefox Version is 112.0

In Chrome and Edge the solution works as expected, can someone help me?

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207095/issue-with-prefers-color-scheme-media-query It comments on FF and Chrome differences, though I appreciate it isn't exactly your linking scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same problem. Couldn't find any remedy anywhere ☹️ so I resorted to using JS instead [to detect which mode the browser is currently using and use a different favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55252008/17695225). This works with OS level mode change and should work on all browsers.